# I want to add a total at the top of my bar chart using ggplot2 in R. When I try, I'm getting the value of each row instead of the total

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and have created a bar chart using

```
ggplot(df_mountainorframemodelsales, aes(x = FrameOrMountain, y = salestotal, fill= FrameOrMountain)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ggtitle("Frame and Mountain Bikes Total Sales")
```

Which gives me a standard chart with two columns. I want to add a total at the top of each column, however when I try it is giving me a big cluster of numbers at the bottom of the chart. I think it is each individual total rather than the sum of them all together. How do I get the total for all mountains and all frames?

This is the code I've tried

```
ggplot(df_mountainorframemodelsales, aes(x = FrameOrMountain, y = salestotal, fill= FrameOrMountain)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=salestotal), vjust=0) +
  ggtitle("Frame and Mountain Bikes Total Sales")
```

[image: this is what I get]

I've tried searching for answers but all the other problems are with stacked bar charts. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. Use `dput()` .https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `data=` used by specific geoms, such as

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = disp), vjust = 0,
            data = ~ aggregate(disp ~ cyl, data = ., FUN = sum)) +
  ggtitle("Total Displacement by Number of Cylinders")
```

[image]

This highlights that you may want to `expand=` the y-axis to allow room for the top labels. Alternatively, you can change `vjust=1.2` or some number over 1 so that it is enclosed within the bar, though this will have problems when bars have extremely low totals (so I think `expand=` with `vjust=0` is safer).

(I'm not saying this is an awesome plot: `cyl` being shown as a discrete vice continuous variable would make a lot of sense, and perhaps other aspects that would make *this* comparison better. My point of not doing that was to stay as close to your original code as possible.)